# How to generate a splatter chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to get a chart for the following.

I have different groups -- Fiance, HR , IT, Maintenance -- and for each one, I have  on the X axis a  pick list of choices to show interest (very low, low, medium, high and very high).

Then on the Y axis, I have a pick list again for each one to show influence, with choices of very low, low, medium, high and very high.

I am trying to get a splatter chart that would show each category based on the selection.  For example, if I would select Finance, I might choose high for interest and low for influence.  This is the idea of the kind of chart I want to produce:

[image: https://imgur.com/gallery/bf8ftzf]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use LibreOffice Calc, so the charting options are a little different.  I was able to get something pretty similar using an XY (scatter) chart:

[image]

I assigned values of 1-5 for V Low to V High.  Then plotted the data.  I got the point labels by turning on data labels and giving it the range containing the names.

I set each axis to min: 0, max: 5, interval: 1, no grid lines, no axis labels.  Then I used the axis titles for the labels.  I set the font to bold and slightly larger, typed in the labels, and then manually added spaces to get them to align with the grid points.

You can do more with text boxes, since you would still want axis titles.

Comment: I will try to replicate this afternoon, thank you very much. I will post my results. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly and i was abble to do it in excel. Thank you very much.